# Math integral in Solidity

Tags: solidity, math

I have a particular bonding curve to integrate into Solidity. I have the function and would like to know if there is a Solidity contract that does math integral.

Something equivalent to this python package https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy//reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html but for Solidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no Solidity contract that does Math Integral. If there is, the manipulation of data would cost money if done on-chain.

Comment: true effectively this could be expensive! I'll integrate directly with the primitive then! Thank you for the quick reply